# conectar em 2 bancos com PDO

Tags: php, mysql

Ola, me conecto em um banco , como eu faria para me conectar com mais outro, que possui o mesmo login e senha dentro do mesmo servidor ? segue minha função:

```
function conectaBanco() {

    $hostname='dbprovider.rede.local';
    $username='root';
    $password='8asd331221!';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=Provider",$username,$password,
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $dbh;
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

no caso como eu faço aqui para me conectar com o outro banco, exemplo quero colocar

```
$dbh2 = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=Provider2",$username,$password,
```

mas não funcionou !!! alguem pode ajudar ?  o erro é Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null line 48 e nessa linha tem

```
$dbh = conectaBanco();
```

Comment: Por que "não funcionou"? Deu algum erro? Qual? Aliás, parece ser o mesmo servidor, apenas *databases* diferentes, então por que, ao invés de criar duas conexões, não utiliza a mesma com o `use Provider2`?

Comment: apenas cria funções separadas uma para cada banco

Comment: Eu criaria uma função com uma propriedade e um switch ou if interno, assim padroniza e facilita. Exemplo: `connDB('BD1'), connDB('BD2'), connDB('BD3')`, etc Agora o motivo do erro, pode ser instância, permissão de usuário, nome errado do BD, etc... Se não colocar o erro, não dá para adivinhar.

Comment: @rbz muita boa ideia, penso que o erro dele é que esta instanciando duas conexões e retornando apenas uma

Comment: o erro é    Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null line 48       e nessa linha tem    $dbh = conectaBanco();

Comment: tenho que mudar tudo pra $dbh2  ?

Comment: anexa o erro a pergunta e o código em questão

Comment: @rbz seguirei esse padrão de função para conexão a partir de agora, antes fazia uma para cada banco, ótima idéia

Comment: @rbz pode dar um exemplo de como seria essa função ?

Comment: Postado. Mas lembre-se, é básico, em cima de seu código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um exemplo básico, sobre sua questão:

```
function conectaBanco($nomeBD) {

    switch ($nomeBD) {

        # Servidor 1, Banco de dados 1
        case 'BD1':
        $hostname='192.168.0.1';
        $dbname='banco1';
        $username='root';
        $password='xx1!';
        break;

        # Servidor 1, Banco de dados 2
        case 'BD2':
        $hostname='192.168.0.1';
        $dbname='banco2';
        $username='root';
        $password='xx1!';
        break;

        # Servidor 2, Banco de dados 1
        case 'BD3':
        $hostname='192.168.0.100';
        $dbname='banco3';
        $username='root';
        $password='yy2!';
        break;

        # Servidor 3, Banco de dados 1
        default:
        $hostname='dbprovider.rede.local';
        $dbname='bd_padrao';
        $username='root';
        $password='zz3!';
        break;
    }

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password,
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $dbh;
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Usando a função:

```
$obj = new ClasseConexao;
$obj -> conectaBanco('BD2');
```